# Is the {{ field_file }} token broken within views?

Tags: views, 8

I am using Drupal 8 and I have a node with a file field. In one node, the uploaded file has spaces in it's filename. When I view the node directly, the shown file url is:

> path/to/files/foo%20bar.pdf

And clicking the link opens the pdf just fine.

In views, I have a block of nodes' files with a global custom text field:

```
<span class="file-type {{ field_term_icon }}"></span>
<span class="file-title">{{ title }}</span>
<span class="file-meta">{{ extension }} / {{ filesize }}</span>
```

which itself has checked "Output this field as a custom link" while the link path is `{{ field_file }}`, but the output link becomes:

> path/to/files/foo%2520bar.pdf

To me it looks like the url is decoded twice. Was this introduced in a recent update? How to fix it?